# Subtract time to time column

Tags: python, pandas

I got the column of a dataframe:

```
print(df["Hour"])

           Hour 
0      01:21:46  
1      01:22:16  
2      01:22:46  
3      01:25:16  
4      01:25:46
```

It says that the column type is object, but when I try to convert with `pd.to_datetime`, says `TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`.
The fact is that I'm trying to subtract the time 00:00 to every row on that column, so I can convert the result to minutes. I tried creating `a=pd.to_datetime("00:00")` but it includes the present date, and I only want the time I wrote before.

I tried with `df["newhour"]=df["Hour"]-a` but it show the error: `TypeError: descriptor '__sub__' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'`.

I know the other solution is to transform every time to minutes, so I tried with `df["Hour"].dt.seconds`, but it show the error: `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values.`

Hel please!!

Comment: Could you add your desired output?

Comment: Yes! For example, if I have `01:21:46` I'd like to convert that on minutes (81 min) or seconds (4906 seconds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is an evidence that your column contains `datetime.time` objects. The standard `pd.to_datetime` can only convert `str` or `datetime.datetime` objects. So you must first convert each hour to an acceptable format. Here I would convert everything to seconds:

```
df['Hour'].apply(lambda x: x.hour * 3600 + x.minute * 60 + x.second)
```

It gives an integer  `Series` that you can now easily process (divide by 60. to convert it into minutes, or...):

```
0    4906
1    4936
2    4966
3    5116
4    5146
```

Answer (score 1):

To get minutes or seconds you can simply do something like this:

```
df1['Minutes'] = round(pd.to_datetime(df1['Hour']).apply(lambda x: x.hour * 60 + x.minute + x.second / 60), 1)
df['Seconds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour']).apply(lambda x: x.hour * 3600 + x.minute * 60 + x.second)
```

To get the difference in let's say seconds you could then use `.shift()`

```
df['Seconds_diff'] = df['Seconds'] - df['Seconds'].shift()
```

Answer (score 1):

The dt accessor is 'dt.second'. So I think we can subtract from it. Ignore '1900-01-01' as I converted it with 'to_datetime'.

```
df['Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour'], format='%H:%M:%S')
df['seconds_diff'] = (df['Hour'].dt.minute - df['Hour'].shift().dt.minute)*60+(df['Hour'].dt.second - df['Hour'].shift().dt.second)

    Hour    seconds_diff
0   1900-01-01 01:21:46 NaN
1   1900-01-01 01:22:16 30.0
2   1900-01-01 01:22:46 30.0
3   1900-01-01 01:25:16 150.0
4   1900-01-01 01:25:46 30.0
```